# Searching and reading from file with python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to search for a specific words in a file and print it.

Here is my code:

```
import os # os directory library

# Searching for a keyword Name and returning the name if found
def scanName(file):
    name = 'Fake'
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as file1:
        for line in file1:
            for word in line.split():
                temp = word
                if temp.lower() == 'name'.lower():
                    name = word[word.index("name") + 1]
    return name



# To find all files ending with txt in a folder
for file in os.listdir("C:\Users\Vadim\Desktop\Python"):
   if file.endswith(".txt"):
       print scanName( file )
```

Now the function return the name as fake although a do have names in my txt files.

Two txt files with string "name: some name"

How do i fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you supposed to be opening the files? Your avatar is hilarious, very racey is that allowed on SO? Your question however is unclear. Can you clarify?

Comment: thanks for that. well now i am trying to open the file, how do use the location of a file i found and sent to scanName func?

Comment: it stuck with me from my google+ account that i never used :) just a private joke with a friend

Comment: If it is not a typo, your file contains the line `name: some name` which will be splitted into `["name:", "some", "name"]`. And of course `"name:" != "name"`. Maybe you'd rather split with `line.split(:)`?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `'name'.lower()` with `name.lower()`, because you are now checking with the *string* `name`, instead of the *variable* `name`.

Comment: I want to scan for a string "name" in the text files and to save the name which comes afterwards.. i should use 'name' arent I?

Comment: @Kiper `'name'.lower()` will only lowercase the actual string "name", not the variable called `name`. Your code will only ever match against the string "name", not "fake". Get it?

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier not to check, line by line and word by word, instead simply check for the word with `if (word) in`:

```
import os # os directory library

# Searching for a keyword Name and returning the name if found
def scanName(file):
    name = 'larceny'
    with open(file, 'r') as file1:
        lines = file1.read()
        if name in lines.lower():
            return name

# To find all files ending with txt in a folder
for file in os.listdir("C:\Users\Vadim\Desktop\Python"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        if scanName(file):
            print( file )
```

Here the entire contents of the file are read in as the variable `lines`, we check for the searched for word, returning the name of the file, although we could just return `True`.
If the function returns a result, we print the name of the file.